# how to prevent error "no space left on device" when deploying multi container docker application on AWS beanstalk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, docker-compose, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a multi container docker application, which contains a java spring application, and a couple of vue.js applications. I use AWS Beanstalk as I don't have experience setting up directly an EC2 instance, AWS Beanstalk seems the simpler way to deploy a multi container docker application to me.

But after making some changes to my application, when I try to deploy it on the AWS beanstalk console, I get always an error "no space left on device". Could you give me some advice on how to fix this space issue?

Thank you.

Comment: Why not increase the volume?

Comment: I did that from 8Gb to 16Gb and still didn't work.

Comment: So you did it incorrectly. You have to describe in detail what exactly did you do.

Comment: I went to EC2 admin, selected the EC2 instance created for the Beanstalk application, then selected "storage" and increased volume size from 8Gb to 16Gb ... if that is not correct, could you tell me how to do it? Thanks

Comment: Once you increased the size you need to go into your container and run:

# lsblk
# growpart /dev/<<name_of_folder>> 1

It will grow your partition to the new size of the EBS volume.

Answer (score 0):

Just changing the volume size is not enough. You also have to extend the associated partition in your instance.

The procedure is described in aws docs https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/recognize-expanded-volume-linux.html