# Elastic Beanstalk Docker deploy fails with "no space left on device"

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-ecr

I am following a tutorial to deploy a Flask application with Docker to AWS Elastic Beanstalk (EB).  I created an AWS Elastic Container Registry (ECR) and ran some commands which successfully pushed the Docker image to the ECR:

```
docker build -t app-backend
docker tag app-backend:latest [URL_ID].dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/app-backend:latest
docker push [URL_ID].dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/app-backend:latest
```

Then I tried to deploy to EB:

```
eb init (selecting a Docker EB application I created on the AWS GUI)
eb deploy
```

On "eb init" I get the error "Cannot setup CodeCommit because there is no Source Control setup, continuing with initialization", but I assume this can be ignored as it otherwise looked fine.  On "eb deploy" though, the deployment fails.  In "eb-engine.log" (found in the AWS GUI), I see error messages like:

[ERROR] An error occurred during execution of command [app-deploy] - [Docker Specific Build Application]. Stop running the command. Error: failed to pull docker image: Command /bin/sh -c docker pull [URL_ID].dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/app-backend:latest failed with error exit status 1. Stderr:failed to register layer: Error processing tar file(exit status 1): write /root/.cache/pip/http/5/e/7/3/b/[long number]: no space left on device

When I manually run the pull command the error references (locally, not from the EB instance), the command seems to respond as expected:

```
docker pull [URL_ID].dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/app-backend:latest
```

What could be causing this deployment failure?

My Dockerrun.aws.json file looks like this:

```
{
    "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": "1",
    "Image": {
      "Name": "[URL_ID].dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/app-backend",
      "Update": "true"
    },
    "Ports": [
      {
        "ContainerPort": 5000,
        "HostPort": 5000
      }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by following [how to prevent error "no space left on device" when deploying multi container docker application on AWS beanstalk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71933690/how-to-prevent-error-no-space-left-on-device-when-deploying-multi-container-do).

Basically you find your Elastic Beanstalk instance in the EC2 AWS GUI, you modify the volumes to add space to the EB instance.  Then you follow the link in that Stack Overflow post to repartition your EB instance by SSHing into it with eb ssh and then using commands like `df -H` and `lsblk` to see how much space in in each partition.  And use commands like:

```
sudo growpart /dev/xvda 1
sudo xfs_growfs -d /
```

to repartition the hard drive as to use all the new space you added in the AWS EC2 GUI.  You can check with `df -H` and `lsblk` to see if the repartitioning gave you more space.

Then the `eb deploy` command should work.  If SSH isn't setup yet, you may have to do `eb ssh --setup` first.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following option setting on my EB environment to resolve this issue.

```json
{
  namespace: 'aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration',
  optionName: 'RootVolumeSize',
  value: '250', // in GB. with what ever the default is for t3.2xLarge, Docker pull in fails with disk space error
},
```

I believe if using the various EB config files the format is something like follows but I've not tested:

```yaml
aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration:
  RootVolumeSize:250
```

For context, I'm also using the Dockerrun.aws.json v1 way. The image is on an ECR public repo in our account. And I'm deploying the EB infrastructure using AWS CDK v2 (which at the time of writing only has L1 constructs so effectively one-to-one with CloudFormation).

I was using a t3.2xlarge. iirc the default root volume size varies by instance type.

Docs on the namespace: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options-general.html#command-options-general-autoscalinglaunchconfiguration